# Emacs : initial window size

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically setting Emacs frame size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335487/programmatically-setting-emacs-frame-size)

The initial emacs window size depends on the number of columns and the font (family+size). 
I set those parameters in my `.emacs` using :

```
(setq default-frame-alist
      '((font . "Menlo-13")
        (width . 80)))
```

When emacs starts, the initial window opens with a size calculated using the default internal font and then resizes itself when the `.emacs` is read.

Do you know any tip to avoid this resize.

I use emacs for MacOSX. (http://emacsformacosx.com/)

Thank you

Comment: also take a look at the answer re: [-geomerty command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335487/programmatically-setting-emacs-frame-size/335518#335518)

Comment: Thanks, this works  .. `open -n -a Emacs --args --font "Menlo-13"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set both `default-frame-alist` and `initial-frame-alist`. If you set them to the same value I think you will see no change from one to the other.

Comment: This is wrong. Initial-frame-alist defaults to default-frame-alist anyway if not set otherwise.