# How do I provide a command-line option to emacsclient?

Tags: emacs

I start emacsclient using:

```
emacsclient -a "" -c
```

This opens a frame connected to the emacs daemon, and starts the daemon if it's not already started. Great, this works fine.

However, I like opening my emacs frames maximized. With emacs, I would use -mm. However, that doesn't work with emacsclient. How do I make this work?

(It seems I could make something work by adding a shell file like so: `emacsclient -a "myshell.sh" -c`, where the shell file is: `emacs -mm`, but I haven't been able to make that work - the server doesn't stay up.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible however those settings could be defined in your .emacs or in you .Xressources. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/335487/1069569).

Answer (score 16):

You can add the following line to .emacs, so that Emacs can be started with the window maximized. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-Parameters.html#Size-Parameters for details.

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
```

Emacs client accepts `-F` option, where you can specify frame parameters, so the above example would be:

```
emacsclient -c -a "" -F "((fullscreen . maximized))"
```

Comment: `emacsclient -c -a "" -F "((fullscreen . maximized))"` is really handy! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to run emacsclient fullscreen, which was my case.

`man emacsclient` shows emacsclient has `-F` option:

```
-F, --frame-parameters=ALIST
       set the parameters of a newly-created frame.
```

In Emacs Manual, which is an info file, section [`(emacs) emacsclient Options`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html) has more information. Specifically for this question [`(elisp) Size Parameters`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-Parameters.html) mentions `fullscreen` parameter. To run emacsclient fullscreen, you need to supply an alist, with one element being `(fullscreen . fullboth)` like that:

```
emacsclient -c -F "((fullscreen . fullboth))"
```

Answer (score 2):

emacsclient provides the `--eval` (`-e` for short) command line option for executing arbitrary Emacs Lisp code, so you can visit a file and call `suspend-frame` from the command line like so:

```
emacsclient -a "" -c --eval "(progn (find-file \"/tmp/my-file\") (suspend-frame))"
```

You could put this in a script, e.g:

```
#!/bin/bash
emacsclient -a "" -c --eval "(progn (find-file \"$1\") (suspend-frame))"
```

Comment: OK, but that wasn't the question... The question was how to run command-line options like `-mm`

Comment: Emacs is open source, it should be fairly straightforward to modify emacsclient.c to create your own version of emacsclient which accepts -mm.