# Windows 7, how to tell another window to "snap" to maximum vertical size? And how to do that in elisp?

Tags: windows-7, emacs, elisp

I recently discovered how on Windows in emacs elisp I can maximize an emacs frame: [How do I set the size of Emacs' window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92971/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-emacs-window/3538748#3538748).

```
(defun w32-maximize-frame ()
  "Maximize the current frame"
  (interactive)
  (w32-send-sys-command 61488))
```

What I would prefer to do is have my emacs window "snap" to it's maximum vertical size using Windows 7 "snap" feature.

```
(defun w32-snap-max-vertical-frame ()
  "Maximize the vertical size of the current frame"
  (interactive)
  ; insert magic here
  )
```

Is there a similar windows message I can send to any window, or my emacs window to have it snap to maximum vertical size?

(As a start, I can google that 61488 above is 0xF300 and corresponds to WM_SYSCOMMAND SC_MAXIMIZE which is an entry in a window's system menu, and "snap to vertical" is not in that menu, so I don't think it would occur through a WM_SYSCOMMAND message....)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog post](http://ciantic.blogspot.com/2010/06/aero-snap-vertical-maximize-winapi.html), you need to execute:

```
PostMessage(hwndTarget, WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK, HTTOP, 0);
```

I had a look, but it looks like emacs doesn't have a `w32-send-mesage` equivalent. If you do find one, `WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK` is 163, and `HTTOP` is 12.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking.  You speak of both Emacs frames and Emacs windows, but I still somehow get the impression that perhaps you really mean that you want to maximize a frame but in the vertical directon only. Is that right?

If so, see command `maximize-frame-vertically` in [`frame-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-cmds.el). There are also commands `maximize-frame-horizontally` and `maximize-frame`, and commands to restore the frame to its sizes (vertical, horizontal, or both) before maximizing.

Comment: That was very useful, and will probably suffice.  It's slightly different that what I want, but hey, I'll take it, thank you. "Windows Snap" has a very nice property in that I have two different monitors of differing vertical heights, and a snapped window when it moves from monitor to monitor will re-adjust its height to fit each window maximally.