# set the window size of emacs on Window 7

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

I want to set the window size (maybe it is the `frame` in emacs speaking). I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11912263/930125) for the config. It works, but something happened that confused me. for example, if I set the width 80 and the height 30. When I start the emacs. It initialize to wider than 80  and higher than 30 which I set previously, then in a flash, it shrinked to the width 80 and height 30.

What I want to ask is why it appeared like this? can I set the window size as soon as the emacs initialized? How?

a similar thing happened with the toolbar. I disable the toolbar like this 
`(tool-bar-mode 0)`

when I initialize the emacs, the toolbar appears, but in a flash it disappeared. FYI, I put the `(tool-bar-mode 0)` in the very first line of the .emacs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the strangely resizing window:

Basically, Emacs brings up its window (frame) before it reads your `.emacs`. Obviously it has to be *some* size. Of course, this is customizable. On Unix systems, you do this by setting an X resource, which works a bit like an environment variable: Emacs can check for the setting when it first runs before loading up all the elisp-parsing machinery and getting to work on your .emacs. On Windows, I think you can set these variables through the registry. See [this EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsWindowsRegistry) for a description of how to set variables in the registry. You want the `Emacs.Geometry` key.

I don't know if it's possible to change `tool-bar-mode` as an X resource. I didn't bother, since the appearing and disappearing tool bar was much less irritating than a moving window!

Comment: thx, my Window 7 version is 64bit I need to use the `regedit` path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\GNU\Emacs`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHIN\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\GNU\Emacs` to set the `Emacs.Geometry`  and the `"Emacs.ToolBar"="OFF"` to solve to `tool-bar-mode` problem.